# How to reload marker and add animation to marker when position change?

Tags: android, google-maps, tracking

Below is my code Here I added markers of bus. Now what I want that when my webservice call in every 30 second then only one marker is refreshing and another one in overriding. One more thing I want then when marker location changed then my marker are blink and move to new position but I want to add animation so user feel that bus goes on road. How can I achieve this?

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, OnMapReadyCallback, DirectionFinderListener {

    private SQLiteHandler db;
    private SessionManager session;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result;
    final static int REQUEST_LOCATION = 199;
    ImageView btnPreference, btnLocation, btnPassword, btnProfile;
    Spinner spinnerShift, spinnerStops;
    List<String> ShiftArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    final List<Integer> ShiftValueArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<String> StopArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    final List<Integer> StopValueArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int selected_shift, selected_stop;
    GridView gridView;
    private List<Routes> routeList = new ArrayList<Routes>();
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;
    GPSTracker gps;
    List<Marker> originMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Marker> MyLocation1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Marker> waypointsMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
    GoogleMap mMap;
    List<Marker> buslocation = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Marker> destinationMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Polyline> polylinePaths = new ArrayList<>();
    Handler handler;
    boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
    ConnectionDetector cd;
    Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
    Circle circle;
    Marker marker, busMarker;
    String startLoc, endLocation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        FindViewById();

        CheckGpsStatus();

    }

    public void CheckGpsStatus() {

        final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();

            cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
            isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

            if (isInternetPresent) {
                apiShift();
            } else {
                final SweetAlertDialog alert = new SweetAlertDialog(MapActivity.this, SweetAlertDialog.WARNING_TYPE);
                alert.setTitleText("No Internet");
                alert.setContentText("Please connect to internet..");
                alert.show();
            }


            handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(runLocation, 30000);

            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        } else {

            apiShift();

            handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(runLocation, 30000);

            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    public void apiShift() {

        VolleyWebService.makeJsonObjectRequest(MapActivity.this, Request.Method.GET, AppConfig.ShiftData, null, new VolleyResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                try {

                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
                    JSONArray json_user = jObj.getJSONArray("Message");
                    for (int i = 0; i < json_user.length(); i++) {

                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = json_user.getJSONObject(i);
                            ShiftArrayList.add(obj.getString("shift_name"));
                            ShiftValueArrayList.add(Integer.valueOf(obj.getString("shift_id")));

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MapActivity.this, R.layout.spinner, ShiftArrayList);
                    dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    spinnerShift.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String message) {
                Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "Sorry something went wrong..Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        spinnerShift.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                selected_shift = Integer.parseInt(ShiftValueArrayList.get(position).toString());
                String shift_id = ShiftValueArrayList.get(position).toString();

                apiRoutes(shift_id);

                apiStops(shift_id);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void apiStops(final String shiftId) {

        String url = AppConfig.StopData + "shift_id=" + shiftId;

        VolleyWebService.makeJsonObjectRequest(MapActivity.this, Request.Method.GET, url, null, new VolleyResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                try {
                    StopArrayList.clear();
                    StopValueArrayList.clear();
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
                    JSONArray json_user = jObj.getJSONArray("Message");

                    for (int i = 0; i < json_user.length(); i++) {

                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = json_user.getJSONObject(i);
                            StopArrayList.add(obj.getString("stop_name"));
                            StopValueArrayList.add(Integer.valueOf(obj.getString("stop_id")));

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MapActivity.this, R.layout.spinner_stop, StopArrayList);
                    dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    spinnerStops.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String message) {
                Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "Sorry something went wrong..Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        spinnerStops.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                selected_stop = Integer.parseInt(StopValueArrayList.get(position).toString());
                String stop_id = StopValueArrayList.get(position).toString();

                apiDrawRoute(shiftId, stop_id);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

    }

    public void apiRoutes(String shift_id) {

        String url = AppConfig.RouteData + "shift_id_tabular=" + shift_id;

        VolleyWebService.makeJsonObjectRequest(MapActivity.this, Request.Method.GET, url, null, new VolleyResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
                    if (mainObj != null) {
                        routeList.clear();
                        JSONArray list = mainObj.getJSONArray("Message");
                        if (list != null) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject elem = list.getJSONObject(i);

                                Routes routes = new Routes();
                                routes.setSrNo(elem.getString("rn"));
                                routes.setName(elem.getString("location"));
                                routes.setTime(elem.getString("actual_time"));
                                routes.setStatus(elem.getString("run_status"));
                                routeList.add(routes);

                                //}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(MapActivity.this, routeList);
                    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String message) {
                Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "Sorry something went wrong..Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);

        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

        result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());

        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                final Status status = result.getStatus();

                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:

                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:

                        try {

                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            status.startResolutionForResult(
                                    MapActivity.this,
                                    REQUEST_LOCATION);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {

                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:

                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_LOCATION:
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK: {

                        break;
                    }
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED: {

                        finish();
                        break;
                    }
                    default: {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.logout:
                db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());
                session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
                session.setLogin(false);
                db.deleteUsers();

                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void apiDrawRoute(String shiftId, String stopId) {
        String url = AppConfig.RouteData + "shiftid=" + shiftId + "&stopid=" + stopId;
        VolleyWebService.makeJsonObjectRequest(MapActivity.this, Request.Method.GET, url, null, new VolleyResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                try {

                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
                    JSONArray json_user = jObj.getJSONArray("Message");
                    List<String> wp = null;
                    for (int i = 0; i < json_user.length(); i++) {

                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = json_user.getJSONObject(i);

                            wp = new ArrayList<String>();

                            for (int w1 = 0; w1 < json_user.length(); w1++) {
                                wp.add(obj.getString("waypoints_latitude") + ',' + obj.getString("waypoints_longitude") + '|');
                            }
                               sendRequest(obj.getString("start_location"), obj.getString("end_location"), wp);
                            startLoc = obj.getString("start_location");
                            endLocation = obj.getString("end_location");

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    sendRequest(startLoc, endLocation, wp);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String message) {
                Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "Sorry something went wrong..Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        spinnerShift.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                selected_shift = Integer.parseInt(ShiftValueArrayList.get(position).toString());
                String shift_id = ShiftValueArrayList.get(position).toString();

                apiRoutes(shift_id);

                apiStops(shift_id);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.clear();
        MyLocation1.clear();
        gps = new GPSTracker(MapActivity.this);
        if (gps.CanGetLocation()) {
            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

            LatLng mylocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mylocation, 10));
        } else {

        }
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }


    public Runnable runLocation = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            gps = new GPSTracker(MapActivity.this);

            MyLocation1.clear();
            if (gps.CanGetLocation()) {
                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                LatLng mylocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                if (marker != null) {
                    marker.remove();
                }
                if (circle != null) {
                    circle.remove();
                }
                if (busMarker != null) {
                    busMarker.remove();
                }

                marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.location))
                        .title("My Location")
                        .position(mylocation));

                circle = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                        .center(mylocation)
                        .radius(1000)
                        .strokeColor(0x10000000)
                        .fillColor(0x10000000));
            } else {

            }

            String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";
            String url = AppConfig.RouteData + "i=1&" + "y=1";

            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {

                        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
                        JSONArray json_user = jObj.getJSONArray("Message");
                        for (int i = 0; i < json_user.length(); i++) {

                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = json_user.getJSONObject(i);

                                Double currLat = obj.getDouble("actual_lat");
                                Double currLong = obj.getDouble("actual_long");
                                LatLng hcmus = new LatLng(currLat, currLong);


                                busMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bus))
                                        .title("Bus No" + obj.getString("bus_id"))
                                        .position(hcmus));


                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "Sorry something went wrong..Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_json_obj);

            MapActivity.this.handler.postDelayed(MapActivity.this.runLocation, 30000);
        }

    };

    private void sendRequest(String Sl, String El, List Wp) {
        String origin = Sl.toString();
        String destination = El.toString();
        List waypoints = Wp;
        if (origin.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter origin address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if (destination.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter destination address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        try {
            new DirectionFinder(MapActivity.this, origin, destination, waypoints).execute();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDirectionFinderStart() {


        if (originMarkers != null) {
            for (Marker marker : originMarkers) {
                marker.remove();
            }
        }

        if (destinationMarkers != null) {
            for (Marker marker : destinationMarkers) {
                marker.remove();
            }
        }

        if (polylinePaths != null) {
            for (Polyline polyline : polylinePaths) {
                polyline.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDirectionFinderSuccess(List<Route> routes) {
        polylinePaths = new ArrayList<>();
        originMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
        destinationMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
        waypointsMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
        buslocation = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Route route : routes) {
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(route.startLocation, 16));
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDuration)).setText(route.duration.text);
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDistance)).setText(route.distance.text);

            originMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
                    .title(route.startAddress)
                    .position(route.startLocation)));

            for (int i = 0; i < route.jlegs.size(); i++) {
                destinationMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED))
                        .title(route.jaddress.get(i))
                        .position(route.jlegs.get(i))));
            }
            destinationMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED))
                    .title(route.endAddress)
                    .position(route.endLocation)));



            PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions().
                    geodesic(true).
                    color(Color.parseColor("#00B3FD")).
                    width(10);

            for (int i = 0; i < route.points.size(); i++)
                polylineOptions.add(route.points.get(i));

            polylinePaths.add(mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions));

            setUpMapIfNeeded();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your requirement is unclear, please make use of proper english language.

Comment: Hi ScottS multiple latitude and longitude coming from database through web service and I am adding then into marker but when after 30 second my web service get  new lat long then only single marker refresh others are overriding. and I want to add animation when position change.

Comment: This question is too broad, you are asking people to do your work for you, including reading about 1000 lines of code. Please make your question more specific and show how you have tried to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks dash2 but I have used  marker.remove() then its refreshing only one marker and its overriding remain markers. I want to refresh all the markers.